# How Angular handles lazy loading after new app version release

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

Angular bundle with lazy loaded modules contains chunk files that are loaded 'on demand' when user navigates to specific part of the app. Chunk files have hashed names so that they can only be referenced within the same build.

When CI builds new version it removes dist directory and recreates it with new files. Then the server notifies the clients via websocket that new version is available and that they can use the current version for some time but have to reload soon. Basically: 'save your work and reload or we will force you'.

After the browser downloaded initial app files, and user did some work in the app, new version gets released. This release swapps the chunk files, but user still has the local base version in browser. My question is: how the local instance of Angular will know which files to download?

I was unable to find any specific article about it.

Comment: The hashes are built into script tags of the HTML

Comment: Precisely, so when files change but browser memory still has the old hash in html what will happen ?